# Too many counter groups exception Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.LimitExceededException:
Too many **counter groups**: 51 max=50
```

Problem: I set the max counter groups to 500 as shown in a different answer to a similar question.

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.counters.limit</name>
  <value>1000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.counters.groups.max</name>
  <value>500</value>
</property>
```

(I know that .limit is not supposed be used anymore)

Even though I set the value, I am still getting this error(51 when max is 50).  Furthermore, I am not sure why, but this error occurs only on the last 3 or 4 reducers (after having completed all 32 map jobs and 28 or so reduce jobs). When I look at the counter information, it looks like more than 50 groups were created from the start (the first map job), so I am not sure why the error is happening at the end.

Stacktrace:

```
LimitExceededException: Too many counter groups: 51 max=50]
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.LimitExceededException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.LimitExceededException: Too many counter groups: 51 max=50
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.Limits.checkCounters(Limits.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.Limits.incrCounters(Limits.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounterGroup.addCounter(AbstractCounterGroup.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounterGroup.addCounterImpl(AbstractCounterGroup.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounterGroup.findCounterImpl(AbstractCounterGroup.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounterGroup.findCounter(AbstractCounterGroup.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounterGroup.findCounter(AbstractCounterGroup.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounters.findCounter(AbstractCounters.java:154)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TypeConverter.fromYarn(TypeConverter.java:243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getJobCounters(ClientServiceDelegate.java:383)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getJobCounters(YARNRunner.java:562)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$7.run(Job.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$7.run(Job.java:758)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getCounters(Job.java:758)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$NetworkedJob.getCounters(JobClient.java:379)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapperHelper.isMainSuccessful(LauncherMapperHelper.java:193)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.check(JavaActionExecutor.java:1490)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionCheckXCommand.execute(ActionCheckXCommand.java:182)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionCheckXCommand.execute(ActionCheckXCommand.java:56)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.XCommand.call(XCommand.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.oozie.service.CallableQueueService$CallableWrapper.run(CallableQueueService.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**Caused by:** org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.LimitExceededException: Too many counter groups: 51 max=50
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.Limits.checkGroups(Limits.java:118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounters.addGroup(AbstractCounters.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.counters.AbstractCounters.addGroup(AbstractCounters.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TypeConverter.fromYarn(TypeConverter.java:240)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Have you set mapreduce.job.counters.groups.max to 500 in mapred-site.xml on all cluster nodes ? Also provide more stacktrace instead of single error line.

Comment: for stacktrace, please see edit above..I don't have a mapred-site.xml in my project.  If it helps, this is being run on EMR.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the property should be `mapreduce.job.counters.max` instead of `mapreduce.job.counters.limit`. I am using Hadoop version 2.9.2.

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.counters.max</name>
    <value>1000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.counters.groups.max</name>
    <value>500</value>
</property>
```

I used this configuration in the *mapred-site.xml* file and it worked for me.
Need to restart every node for the config to be applied.